# How do I make a window transparent in KDE?

Tags: kde, configuration

I know I can do this in Unity with compiz. But didn't find a way to do same in KDE. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with full kubuntu-desktop installed.

Btw, I noticed an option for inactive window. But I wanted for active window.

Comment: Just googled the topic and couldn't find anything for active windows. Quite surprising given how customizable KDE is reputed to be.

Comment: Google harder, I remember being able to assign it even to mousewheel+modifier. Unfortunately, I switched to KDE5 (not recommended until Ubuntu updates Qt to 5.5 (16.04?)) and not sure that if I find the solution here it will help you.

Comment: @int_ua I've googled harder already!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) First Go to **System Settings** → **Window Behavior**

[image: window behavior]

2) Open *Window Behavior*, Select *Window Actions* by again selecting *Window Behavior*

[image]

3) In **Inner Window, Titlebar & Frame** section, Use the *Mouse Wheel* action to **Change opacity**

Here is a transparent window

[image]

Comment: Works in KDE5 too.

Comment: In recent KDE builds, it's in Settings > **Window Management** > Window Behavior > **Window Action** > Iner Window, Tilebar and Frame Actions.

Answer (score 6):

1. Click on window actions (top left corner) → More Actions → Special Window Settings

   [image: KWIN - Special Window Settings 1]
2. Go to Appearance & Fixes tab: force any transparency you want for active / inactive state.

   [image: KWIN - Special Window Settings 2]

You can also manage all created rules in single place as with compiz through:

System Settings → Window Behavior → Window Rules

[image: kwin - Window Rules]

Comment: Aren't there any keyboard shortcut like compiz? This is not very efficient solution for daily use i guess

Comment: found a more convenient way, shared it :)

Comment: @AnwarShah, yep that is the best

Answer (score 2):

> System Settings > Shortcuts & Gestures > Global Shortcuts, then select "KWin" from the drop down. Find the options "Decrease opacity of Active window by 5%" and "Increase opacity of Active Window by 5%".

Additional info: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=212&t=98612

Comment: Helpful. But, I've found more intuitive one.

Comment: Yeah, that way indeed looks more convenient :)

Comment: Any way to add a "blur" effect to that command?

Answer (score 0):

**Fully transparent windows in Kubuntu 18.04.2:**

[image]

System settings > Windows Behavior > Windows Actions.

Inactive Inner Window

Inner Window, Titlebar & Frame

Left Button   -- change to Increase Opacity
Middle Button -- change to Increase Opacity
Right Button  -- change to Increase Opacity
Mouse wheel   -- change to Change Opacity

There is an option to the left of these for a key.
On my system it is set at Alt.
I have just left it at that.

Click Apply.

Done.
Now you can click on a window then hold down alt and turn the mouse wheel. The window will now adjust from solid background to fully transparent depending on how much wheel turning you give it.

You can use this action for one or all windows.