# How to set application's transparency/opacity in Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kubuntu, transparency, compositing

With Compton, it's possible to have opacity rules like this:

```
opacity-rule = [ 
            "60:name ~= '^Mahjongg$'",
            "70:name ~= 'Settings - Google Chrome$'",
            "70:name ~= 'Extensions - Google Chrome$'",
            "70:name ~= 'Stylish - Google Chrome$'",
            "50:name ~= '\.pdf - Google Chrome$'",
            "50:class_g *= 'Evince'",
            "95:window_type *= 'dialog'",
            "95:window_type *= 'menu'"
            ];
```

How can I achieve something similar in Kubuntu 16.04 (without using Compton because, if I understand correctly, Kubuntu has its own compositor built into its window manager)?

Comment: Yes, `kwin` handles compositing including transparency. There are various ways to adjust it with the UI - see here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/649027/how-do-i-make-a-window-transparent-in-kde - and also look at "window rules". If you want a programmatic solution, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thnaks, your link does it for me. I'll vote to close my question as a duplicate.